# Is there authentication, as in Google Firebase even in the Google Cloud platform?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I need to identify a similar authentication in Google Cloud Platform like Google Firebase offers. I want to authenticate users by E-Mail and password.

I developed a web app that runs in GCP AppEngine. This web app authenticates users by their E-Mail and password. But I wont host a custom OAuth server. Is there a OAuth server or similar authentication service provided by GCP too?

Or should I use instead Google Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Firebase project linked directly to your GCP project (just find your GCP project in the Firebase project creation dialog).

Depending on the required language, they have a couple of tutorials with explanations on how Firebase Auth and e.g. App Engine can work together with sample codes. See:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

Answer (score 2):

You can of course roll your own authentication, but it's also possible to use Firebase Authentication in combination with your own App Engine backend. Have the users sign in with Firebase Authentication in the client-side app, [send the ID token over a secure connection from the client to your App Engine server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients), and then [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) in your App Engine code.

Comment: GCP does not have such a Auth Service?

Comment: What advantages would you expect from that? There's https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/, but it's pretty much just a layer around Firebase Authentication.

Comment: Your answer is helpful as well. Thank you very much.